# crontab date definition for only second Wednesday of the month

Tags: cron

How do I define crontab date for second Wednesday (of every months) only? I would appreciate your help.

Comment: The cron schedule is too rough a tool for this. You will probably want to use `0 0 * * WED` to run a job every Wednesday, but point to a shell script that validates the week of the month before running a given task.

Comment: I think that 1. Wednesday in a month always will be between day 1 to 7 and so second Wednesday in month must be between day 8 to 14 ...  so something like `0 0 8-14 * WED .....` should do it. Off course the two first values (minutes and hour) can be any legal minute and hour value.

Comment: @SorenA https://crontab.guru/#0_0_8-14_*_wed That runs on day 8 through 14 AND wednesday :) You need a little adjustment: https://crontab.guru/tips.html   It probably requires 7 lines `0 0 */8 * WED`, `0 0 */9 * WED`, `0 0 */10 * WED`, `0 0 */11 * WED`, `0 0 */12 * WED`, `0 0 */13 * WED`,   `0 0 */14 * WED`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked for cron so only using cron you can do this using bash's date as a 2nd test:

```
0   0  8-14 *   *   [ "$(date '+\%u')" = "3" ] && {your script}
```

- On every hour of days 8 through 14
- and then check for wednesday with bash's date. Daynumber 3 is wednesday

The comment from Soren A is [a little wrong](https://crontab.guru/tips.html) (BUT the man page is also wrong). `0 0 8-14 * WED` = “At 00:00 on every day-of-month from 8 through 14 **and** on Wednesday.” From the last link:

> Tip 1: If the day-of-month or day-of-week part starts with a *, they form an intersection. Otherwise they form a union. * * 3 * 1 runs on the 3rd day of the month and on Monday (union), whereas * * */2 * 1 runs on every second day of the month only if it's also a Monday (intersection). The [manpage](https://crontab.guru/crontab.5.html) is incorrect about this detail. [More info](https://crontab.guru/cron-bug.html).

Comment: This is very elegant and compact. I'll try it. Thanks Rinzwind

Comment: "Tip 1" from https://crontab.guru/tips.html is very interesting.  You may want to include it in your answer to support the "man page is also wrong" claim.

Comment: @AndrewLowther yeah I thought about it at first and decided not to but you are right, so added :+

Comment: Is backslash in [ "$(date '+\%u')" = "3" ] necessary?

Comment: yes, see `man 5 crontab` "Percent-signs (%) in the command, unless escaped with backslash (\\),  will be changed into newline characters, and all data after the 
first % will be sent to the command as standard input."

Answer (score 4):

Cron can **not** do this natively, but a systemd timer could.

The cron syntax `0 0 8-14 * Wed` will **not** work.  It will match every Wednesday as well as every day between the 8th and 14th.  As [the crontab man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man5/crontab.5.html) says

> The day of a command's execution can be specified by two fields — day of month,  and day  of  week.  If both fields are restricted (i.e., don't start with *), the command will be run when *either* field matches the current time.

systemd timers handle the logic differently and can do what you want.  This syntax would match midnight on the second Wednesday each month.

```
OnCalendar=Wed *-*-8..14 00:00:00
```

**Links**

- https://www.bggofurther.com/2018/02/execute-cron-on-a-specific-day-of-the-month-e-g-second-monday/
- https://www.redpill-linpro.com/sysadvent/2016/12/07/systemd-timers.html

Comment: yes cron can do this ;-)

Comment: Thanks Andrew, good links. I can see that cron alone is not enough for this job as I suspected. I also have a job that needs to be done on the last Friday of each month. I will use one of the suggested secondary checks and filter in the correct date.